# Decode QR code using Zxing

Tags: android, decode, zxing, qr-code

Can anyone please explain how to decode a QR code using Zxing library? A step by step procedure would be very helpful! I've added Zxing Core 2.2 jar to my project library and Contents.java and QRCodeEncoder.java to the main package. Now I'm able to generate the QR code. I'm looking for a decoder example. Also, what permissions are required (or what other changes are required in application manifest)? I don't want to launch third party application intent. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you even try to search for this before asking your question? Look [here](http://bit.ly/1lulEJc)

Comment: Does that suppose to mean anything? Of course I've seen those examples. I got it almost working using:http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/ Unfortunately, I'm getting runtime exception for CaptureActivity..

Comment: When you ask a question on SO you're expected to show a little effort, which you're not showing when looking at your text in the question. If you've tried something, show the code and tell us what problems you encounter...

Comment: If you've encountered issues, list those issues here, otherwise it's hard for others to know what you have tried, and how had those failed.